# std::make_unique and unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr

If I read correctly, [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) says that the following two constructs should be equivalent for non-array types in C++14 and later:

```
make_unique<T>(T());
unique_ptr<T>(new T());
```

I've clearly not understood a subtlety.  Here's an example (the full file with headers and scaffolding is [here](https://gist.github.com/JeffAbrahamson/fda17027a0a5b52982869d447e19e36a). In the example, I expect `cmp3` and `cmp4` to have the same effect, but `cmp4` doesn't compile.

```
template <typename T>
class DbCell {
   public:
    DbCell() {}
    DbCell(const T& v) : value_(v.value_) {}
    DbCell(T&& v) : value_(move(v.value_)) {}
    ~DbCell() {}
   private:
    T value_;
};

struct ChapterStats {
    ChapterStats() {}
};
class ChapterMap {
   public:
    ChapterMap() {}
    ChapterMap(const ChapterMap&) = delete;
    ChapterMap(ChapterMap&& cm) : the_map_(move(cm.the_map_)) {}

   private:
    map<string, unique_ptr<ChapterStats>> the_map_;
};
void foo() {
    DbCell<ChapterMap> cm;

    unique_ptr<DbCell<int>> cmp1 =
        make_unique<DbCell<int>>(DbCell<int>());

    unique_ptr<ChapterMap> cmp2 = make_unique<ChapterMap>(ChapterMap());

    unique_ptr<DbCell<ChapterMap>> cmp3 =
        unique_ptr<DbCell<ChapterMap>>(new DbCell<ChapterMap>());

    // This next fails, even though I think it should be equivalent to cmp3.
    cout << "> cmp4:" << endl;
    unique_ptr<DbCell<ChapterMap>> cmp4 =
        make_unique<DbCell<ChapterMap>>(new DbCell<ChapterMap>());
}
```

Without `cmp4` the output is this (adding appropriate print statements):

```
Constructed ChapterMap.
Constructed DbCell.
> cmp1:
Constructed DbCell.
> cmp2:
Constructed ChapterMap.
Moved ChapterMap.
> cmp3:
Constructed ChapterMap.
Constructed DbCell.
```

With `cmp4`, the compiler error is this:

```
In file included from rgr.cc:6:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/memory:81:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:765:34: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'DbCell<ChapterMap>'
    { return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)); }
                                 ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
rgr.cc:61:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::make_unique<DbCell<ChapterMap>, DbCell<ChapterMap> *>' requested here
        make_unique<DbCell<ChapterMap>>(new DbCell<ChapterMap>());
        ^
rgr.cc:18:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'DbCell<ChapterMap> *' to 'const DbCell<ChapterMap>' for 1st argument; dereference the argument with *
class DbCell {
      ^
rgr.cc:21:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'DbCell<ChapterMap> *' to 'const ChapterMap' for 1st argument
    DbCell(const T& v) : value_(v.value_) {
    ^
rgr.cc:24:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'DbCell<ChapterMap> *' to 'ChapterMap' for 1st argument
    DbCell(T&& v) : value_(move(v.value_)) { cout << "Moved DbCell." << endl; }
    ^
rgr.cc:20:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
    DbCell() { cout << "Constructed DbCell." << endl; }
    ^
1 error generated.
```

One of the pieces that confuses me is that the compiler is complaining about the implicitly deleted `DbCell<ChapterMap>` copy constructor, but I've defined one (that I don't want, but just for the example).

Comment: `make_unique` invokes the constructor of `T` on your behalf; arguments to `make_unique` are passed to the constructor of `T`. So `cmp4` requires a copy or move constructor.

Comment: You did not create a copy/move constructor for `DbCell<T>`, because the ctors you defined take a `T const &` and not a `DbCell<T> const &`.

Comment: `make_unique<T>(T());` is equivalent to `unique_ptr<T>(new T(T()));`

Comment: @AlanBirtles You are correct.  I'm looking for the error in my MRE (that is, why I wrote that specifically).

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, the omission of the template argument on the `DbCell` constructor was the heart of the issue.  (This said, I much appreciated the realisation that I have sometimes accidentally called `make_unique` incorrectly and that the compiler hasn't always warned me.)

Answer (score 9):

These two are *not* identical:

```
   make_unique<T>(T());
   unique_ptr<T>(new T());
```

These two are identical:

```
   make_unique<T>();
   unique_ptr<T>(new T());
```

In the first one you had an extra move/copy ctor involved in the call of `make_unique<T>`.

Answer (score 4):

For `cmp4` you should use

```
unique_ptr<DbCell<ChapterMap>> cmp4 =
        make_unique<DbCell<ChapterMap>>(/*empty*/);
```

`std::make_unique` calls a constructor of its type, which in your case would be a constructor taking a pointer to `DbCell`, which you don't have. This is highlighted by the compiler error message:

```
rgr.cc:18:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'DbCell<ChapterMap> *' to 'const DbCell<ChapterMap>' for 1st argument; dereference the argument with *
```